# Why do xpath querys do not return a result on xhtml pages

Tags: javascript, xpath, content-type

At the moment I am struggling with clientside xpath evaluation. For developing purposes I added:

```
<?php header( 'Content-type: application/xhtml+xml' ); ?>
```

to the top of my page to get parse errors if I produce non valid (x)html. I want to make some xpath queries like `//div`, or `//div[@class='test']` and so on using this code:

```
function xpath( query ){
    var evaluater = new XPathEvaluator();
    var resolver = document.createNSResolver( document.documentElement );
    var iterator = evaluater.evaluate( query, document, resolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );
    var nodes = [];
    var result;
    while( ( result = iterator.iterateNext() ) != null ){
        nodes.push( result );
    }
    return nodes;
};
```

the top of my page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
```

It works fine if the `header(...)` method is commented out, but if it is triggered the xpath queries return no result.

Why is this? What role plays the header for xpath evaluation?

**edit:**

if I drop the xmlns from the html element an switch the `header` - method, this appears:

[image: without xmlns]

Comment: can you post the original html?

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/YL9mWPPu

Comment: IMHO since from the namespace `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'`, the content type of returned data can be inferred thats why setting the content type explicitly is not needed. additionally the meta tag add the respective response headers for the content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your (X)HTML document is parsed by the XML parser (and setting the content type to application/xhtml+xml asks the browser or user agent to parse the document with the XML parser) the XML rules apply and XPath works on this document according to XML rules. In that case all the XHTML elements like `div` are in the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` and for an XPath 1.0 expression to select an element in a namespace you need to use e.g. `//pf:div` where you bind the used prefix (e.g. `pf`) to the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. How you do that depends on the XPath API you use, in the case of the `evaluate` method and the Javascript API you need e.g.

```
document.evaluate('//pf:div', document, function(prefix) { if (prefix === 'pf') return 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'; else return null; }, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```

To explain it the other way, your current path expression `//div` selects elements with local name `div` in **no namespace** and as the elements in the XHTML documents are in the XHTML namespace that path does not select any elements (as long as XML parsing rules apply).

Of course these days with all the browser vendors having made the move to HTML5 to continue to use `text/html` instead of switching to XML based parsing I wonder why you want to serve your documents as XML.

Comment: thank you! this sounds quiet good! I am gonna give it a try in a few hours!

Comment: very cool! your explanation works very fine! I am gonna give much more a try now!! Thank you!